# 365 Guest users cannot sign into Teams

Tags: guest-account, microsoft-teams

- I have a new 365 tenant.
- I have followed the guest checklist for teams several times and everything is configured right: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/guest-access-checklist
- Tried assigning the Teams app to a guest user in Azure AD.

I can only sign into Teams online and the desktop app after clicking the invitation link.  If i try signing in as the guest user to the android app or directly without the link I get the message that I am not part of any organizations.  Microsoft has specifically resolved the feature request to add guest access to the iOS, and desktop apps: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/31478902-guest-access-from-ios-app

I've spent hours googling and have not found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing this information as I was unable to find it elsewhere.  I am going to submit documentation feedback to Microsoft.

- According to my ticket with Microsoft, the feature request for iOS is
  still being worked on even though it was marked complete: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/31478902-guest-access-from-ios-app

> "Ios app currently does not support guest access as far as I have been able to find. Please make ios client fully featured."
>
> "I spoke with the mobile feature team and they confirmed this feature
> shipped at the same time with the desktop app guest access."

- The invitation email link is required for external guest users to be able to sign in.
- When adding guest users to your team, they must be added via Teams to receive both the group welcome email and the Teams welcome email.  Adding a guest to the team via Azure AD or 365 Admin will only send the group welcome email.  Having the guest click on the "Teams" link in the Azure AD group page is not the same as the invitation link in the email.

As far as I can tell, guests + Teams is in a limbo stage.  I am going to try adding the Teams link to the SharePoint page and see if that allows guests that did not get the Teams email to be able to sign in.  Microsoft is not making it easy for guest users to participate without using complicated URLs.

Comment: You really should quote all relevant information from your link.